# C++ function returning auto

Tags: c++, class, auto

I'd like to implement a function in the superclass that also works in the subclass like so:

```
class Super {
   public:
       int x; 
       Super() { x=0; }
       ~Super() {}
       auto changer() { x += 10; return this; }
 };
 class Sub : public Super {
 }
 int main() {
   Sub *sub = new Sub();
   Sub *sub2 = sub->changer();
 }
```

In other words, I want a function that the C++ compiler will assign the correct instance type to, based on the caller. If a Sub object is called, the compiler recognizes that it returns a Sub* pointer. If a Super object is called, the compiler knows its type is Super*.

But can a function that returns auto perform this magic? I tried it, and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you have a reason for making the return type `auto`?  `virtual Super* changer()` would allow the derived to implement `virtual Sub* changer()`.

Comment: All `auto` can know is the base class because it's the base class using `auto`. It can't know  what classes will ultimately be derived from it, but there are tricks like [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) that can be used in some cases. Not sure how applicable it is to this case, though. On examination, not really applicable, but could form the kernel of a solution.

Comment: i'd like you to use templates for it, as they provide something like an `auto` for you.

Comment: Seem like you need [CRTP](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp) but use it with caution. CRTP pattern injects the derived class to base template.

Comment: Side note: `Super` looks to be is an excellent place for a `virtual` destructor

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `auto` per se.  The problem is that you want method to return two different types in the base class and the derived class.  That means you need two different methods.

I would do this with:

```
class Super {
  public:
     ...
     virtual Super* changer() { x += 10; return this; }
};

class Sub : public Super {
    Sub* changer() override { return static_cast<Sub*>(Super::changer()); }
};
```

It's a little bit of repetition, but the meaning is clear and you don't open up a can of worms with CRTP.

The CRTP suggestion gets you to one method by having a non-virtual method in the Base class that returns a Derived class pointer.

```
template <typename Derived>
class Super {
    auto changer() { x += 10; return static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};

class Sub : public Super<Sub> {
};
```

which works as long as `Super` isn't concrete (note that there's no longer a version of `changer()` that returns a `Super*`).  It also forces you to make `Super` a class template.  If you need CRTP for other reasons, then I'd go for it, but the virtual function is a lot simpler.

Comment: Rather than using a `static_cast`, you can just have `Sub::changer` return `this;` directly

Comment: True.  I was just being pedantic to make it clear what was going on.

Comment: You could also make the return type ```auto``` in the virtual function case (if you left the ```static_cast``` in place), but I thought that would be less clear.